# How to get users additional information using Laravel Facebook Socialite

Tags: facebook, laravel-socialite

I am trying to get the users additional information like `gender, birthdate, email, and hometown`. I am using this code below:

```
$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields([
                    'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday', 'location'
            ])->scopes([
                'email', 'user_birthday', 'location'
            ])->user();
```

But my problem for now is it is not getting the user location or hometown, sometimes, it also failed to fetch the users' gender and birthday. How can I access the users' data without using the App review in Facebook for developers.

Comment: Before you get your app reviewed, you can only ask people with a role in your app for those permissions. (And there is no permission named `location`.)

Comment: @04FS Yes. We are the only one accessing it. We are admin of the app. I also have tried `hometown` but is not working.

Comment: why would you "try" stuff, intead of taking a look at the docs? they tell you exactly what permissions there are, and what fields.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

The permissions would be `user_hometown` and `user_location`, according to the docs.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

The fields would be `hometown` and `location`.